# Первая встреча сообщества Stack Overflow на русском в Санкт-Петербурге

Tags: обсуждение, встречи-сообщества

По воле случая, в Санкт-Петербурге собралась небольшая “инициативная группа”, которая выдвинула предложение собраться вместе для живого общения.

**С нетерпением спешу анонсировать первую встречу участников сообщества Stack Overflow на русском в Санкт-Петербурге!**

Stack Overflow на русском - это не социальная сеть, у нас нет списков друзей и личных сообщений, но все, что делается на Stack Overflow на русском, делается исключительно сообществом и для сообщества. Нам кажется, что было бы здорово собраться вместе!

Чтобы организовать встречу, нам необходимо ваша помощь! Если вы планируете посетить мероприятие, пожалуйста, заполните [специальную форму](https://goo.gl/VsYSoJ).

Мы планируем встретиться чуть менее через две недели, 24-го или 25-го июля. Место встречи и тематика определится по результатам опроса. После определения даты, места, времени и тематики, я отпишусь всем участникам по почте, указанной в учётной записи на Stack Overflow на русском.

Ждем ваших откликов!

**Обновление**

[Ссылка на обсуждение встречи в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26128/stack-overflow--).

Comment: для даты/времени лучше чекбоксы

Comment: да и для места/активности.

Comment: Жаль, я в Сибири. Мысленно с вами )

Comment: Да и я в Китае( Мне любопытно, как у вас получичится. Пожалуйста расскажите после встречи.

Comment: @PeterOlson: Qingdao? Ну там хоть пиво есть.

Comment: @VladD Да да, у нас здесь много хорошего пива

Comment: @Nofate Ждем вашей регистрации!

Comment: Как насчет Москвы? С удовольствием бы сходил.

Comment: А когда закончится голосование и будут известны время и место?

Comment: @pavelip постараюсь подвести итоги и отписаться всем зарегестрировавшимся сегодня вечером. Вместе, мы подберем место (за него не голосовали). Как только все нюансы станут известны, сразу же отпишусь в ответе к этому вопросу.

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, Вы не подскажите, а почему теперь имея учетку на stackoverflow ну русском нельзя добавлять сообщения в чат? Вроде пару недель назад учетки на StackExchange не требовалось...

Comment: @margosh Не совсем понял вопрос. Пожалуйста, поясните. Обычно, если у вас есть учетная запись на одном из сайтов сети Stack Exchange, то и на самом Stack Exchange он тоже есть.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, пардон, специально чтобы проверить, вышла из учетки и ... пришлось восстановить пароль :). Раньше, находясь под учеткой Ru.SO, можно было открыть страницу чата, и что-то написать, а сейчас предлагает залогиниться.

Comment: @margosh Система чатов находится на другом домене. Скорее всего, вам просто надо войти в систему используя те же данные для входа, что и на Stack Overflow на русском.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, спасибо, получилось )

Comment: А осенью будет? А то я б с удовольствием, но до осени на острове в северном ледовитом(

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Тут все от нас зависит, если будут желающие, то будет и встреча!