# Встреча сообщества Stack Overflow на русском в Москве и Новосибирске

Tags: обсуждение, встречи-сообщества

Несколько месяцев назад состоялась [встреча участников сообщества в Санкт-Петербурге](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/790/). Как мне кажется, лучше всяких отчетов будет фотография:

[image: Встреча в СПб]

**С нетерпением спешу анонсировать встречу участников сообщества Stack Overflow на русском в Москве и Новосибирске!**

Думаю, ни для кого не секрет, что Stack Overflow – это в первую очередь люди, сообщество знатоков разработки программного обеспечения и энтузиастов программирования, но идея проекта лежит в плоскости создания новых свободных знаний, а не прямом общении участников. Давайте компенсируем это личной встречей, соберемся все вместе!

Чтобы встреча состоялась, нам нужна ваша помощь в её организации! Если вы планируете посетить мероприятие, пожалуйста, заполните специальную форму.

- [Встреча в Москве](https://goo.gl/XzUyfr).
- [Встреча в Новосибирске](https://goo.gl/6X5nrk).

Мы планируем встретиться чуть менее через три недели, 11-го декабря в Москве, и 12-го  декабря в Новосибирске. Место встречи и тематика определится по результатам опроса. После определения места, времени и тематики, я отпишусь всем участникам по почте, указанной в учётной записи на Stack Overflow на русском.

Ждем ваших откликов!

---

Как и в прошлый раз, мы попробуем организовать какую-либо возможность подключиться к общению удаленно. В дополнение, спешу предложить использовать хэштег #stackoverflow при публикации чего -либо со встречи в соц. сетях, если вы ими пользуетесь.

Да, при желании, вы можете принять участие в обеих встречах!

**Обновление**

Если у вас есть идеи и/или соображения по поводу организационных моментов встречи, пожалуйста, не стесняйтесь, напишите об этом!

- **Чат для обсуждения встречи в Москве: [http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32579/](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32579/__)**
- **Чат для обсуждения встречи в Новосибирске: [http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32580/](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32580/__)**

Comment: Ура! Обязательно приду!

Comment: Может тогда #rustackoverflow ? )

Comment: Вроде в этих числах буду в Москве. Может и загляну.

Comment: Николай, так вы в Новосиб прилетите?

Comment: неужели даже девушки есть? о_О

Comment: @NickVolynkin Да! С очень большой вероятностью, часам к 7 доберусь до Новосибирска.

Comment: @Все, кто планирует присоединиться. __Пожалуйста, не забудьте заполнить форму!__

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, а `собака-Все` - это вы ради хохмы или оно работает на оповещение всех отметившихся в посте?..

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, Скорее ради шутки, но внутри компании у нас есть специальные псевдонимы, чтобы обращаться к группе людей.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, а "обычным" людям они доступны?.. Было б удобно что-то подобное иметь в своём распоряжении)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, на сколько я знаю, для этого необходимо создавать специальные группы на сервере, но скорее всего, это невозможно по каким-либо идеологическим причинам, а не техническим.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, эх, жаль) А может как-нибудь можно что-то типа регулярок использовать? Типа `@%я_люблю_закрывать_вопросы` и все пользователи с такой подстрокой в нике уведомляются... Так можно было бы легко партии организовать)))

Comment: А можно подписать, кто где на фото? Думаю, не только мне интересно.

Comment: @VladD Не уверен, на сколько ребята (и девушки) готовы выходить за рамки своего «интернет–Я». На фото есть я – справа, второй от входа. Если кто-то захочет самоидентифицировать себя, будет здорово увидеть их комментарий!

Comment: @VladD: в ноутбуке на фоне ковра — я ))

Answer (score 5):

Шикарно! Я предполагаю что это будет вечер часов 19-21, так что думаю что нужно выбрать место где будет еда. Много еды. Лично я к этому времени буду очень голодный.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Всем  привет я из Новосиба (учусь в СГУПСе) могу обговорить с деканатом и провести мероприятие в универе( засветить данный ресурс по лучше) так как он реально классный. Немного подготовится и провести пару интересных презентаций. А потом сходить бар или покушать. Также в середине декабря планируются конференции на айти тематику.

Comment: Конференции и другие мероприятия на айти-тематику у нас в городе проходят по нескольку в неделю, разного масштаба )

Comment: Спасибо за предложение! Мне кажется, главное – чтобы было интересно всем. Можно создать чат для обсуждения. Единственное ограничение, с моей стороны, что лично я не смогу быть ранее 7 часов вечера в связи с разницей во времени и необходимыми 4мя часами лета из Москвы.

Answer (score 0):

Еду со встречи, народу хоть и не много, но очень классно посидели, спасибо большое за вечер, надеюсь такие мероприятия будут чаще. При необходимости готов помочь в организации))